# Elegant way to parse Calculator.g4 in grammars-v4 using antlr4 listener model

Tags: antlr4, grammar

I learned the basic grammars of antlr4 and tried to build a simple calculator. But, I have no idea how to handle **PLUS | MINUS** and **TIMES | DIV**.

```
expression: multiplyingExpression ((PLUS | MINUS) multiplyingExpression)*;

multiplyingExpression: signedAtom ((TIMES | DIV) signedAtom)*;

signedAtom: PLUS signedAtom | MINUS signedAtom | func_ | atom;
```

(code extracted from [Antlr4 sample calculator grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/calculator/calculator.g4))

It seems like no API can handle **PLUS | MINUS**, because they are not defined like signedAtom/expression, which can be handled in method like `exitXXX`.

Does this mean, the grammar like this can only be parsed in visitor model?

Example:

Here is a extremely simple example code in golang.

### calculator.g4

```
grammar calculator;

expression: atom ((PLUS | MINUS) atom)*;

atom: '1';

PLUS: '+';

MINUS: '-';
WS: [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
```

### Code in Golang listener model

```
func NewCalculatorListenrImpl() *CalculatorListenrImpl {
    return &CalculatorListenrImpl{
        stack: stack.New(),
    }
}

type CalculatorListenrImpl struct {
    BasecalculatorListener
    stack *stack.Stack
}

func (s *CalculatorListenrImpl) ExitExpression(ctx *ExpressionContext) {
    left, op, right := s.stack.Pop().(int), s.stack.Pop().(string), s.stack.Pop().(int)

    switch op {
    case "+":
        s.stack.Push(left + right)
    case "-":
        s.stack.Push(left - right)
    }
}

func (s *CalculatorListenrImpl) ExitAtom(ctx *AtomContext) {
    v, _ := strconv.ParseInt(ctx.GetText(), 10, 32)

    s.stack.Push(int(v))
}
```

I can push the `atom` element to stack in `exitAtom` and then handle the logic in `exitExpression` method. However, there is no listener for `(PLUS | MINUS)`. What I am looking for is method like `exitPLUS` where I can simply push them to stack like `atom`. May be there is other ways to do this? I knostrateforw  their is some magic syntax like `#` and `op=xxx`, but these code fragements are copied from grammars-v4.

Comment: the Calculator.g4 is from repo here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

Comment: It can be parsed any way you want. It's probably easiest to do immediate evaluation through a Visitor, which is reasonably straightforward. Also, I don't see why `(PLUS|MINUS)` is particularly special. Perhaps you should provide your sample Listener code and ask if it can be applied to other Calculator productions.

Comment: For `atom` there is a `exitAtom` method generated by antlr4, I can save the atom value to a stack. I want to save all element like `PLUS` and `atom` and result of `func_` to the stack, then calculate result of `signedAtom` based on the elements in stack, then push the result of `signedAtom` to stack. After that, I can do the same things in function `exitMultiplyingExpression`.  But, there is no way to listen the element like `PLUS`, maybe there should be some functions like `exitPLUS` and `exitMINUS`?